# Http-kit Clojure Framework benchmark

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring, frameworkbenchmarks

I try to run the http-kit clojure benchmark however I have not successfully tried to run it. 
All the source code is available [here](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/tree/master/http-kit).

As you can see (in the part of the whole original code below), I have connected mysql database and setting db_host=localhost and port 8080. The output that I get is: 
http-kit server listens at :8080 (without any error). I think that I have done some mistakes in the https "GET" in the app-routes or in the handler (wrap-json-response app-routes) syntax. Can anyone please give me some advice?

```
(defn start-server [{:keys [port db-host]}]
  (db/use-database! (str "jdbc:mysql://"db-host"/movies?jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&elideSetAutoCommits=true&useLocalSessionState=true&cachePrepStmts=true&cacheCallableStmts=true&alwaysSendSetIsolation=false&prepStmtCacheSize=4096&cacheServerConfiguration=true&prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&traceProtocol=false&useUnbufferedInput=false&useReadAheadInput=false&maintainTimeStats=false&useServerPrepStmts&cacheRSMetadata=true")
                    "root"
                    "")
  ;; Format responses as JSON
  (let [handler (wrap-json-response app-routes)
        cpu (.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime))]
    ;; double worker threads should increase database access performance
    (run-server handler {:port port :thread (* 2 cpu)})
    (println (str "http-kit server listens at :" port))))

;; Define route handlers
(defroutes app-routes

  (GET "http://localhost/http-kit/" [] "Hello, World!")
  (GET "http://localhost/http-kit/json" [] (response {:message "Hello, World!"}))
  (GET "http://localhost/http-kit/db" []
       (response (first (run-queries 1))))
  (GET "http:/localhost/http-kit/db/2" [queries]
       (response (run-queries (get-query-count queries))))
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more information on how you are running this would help. This process works for me, using [the guide here](https://frameworkbenchmarks.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Development/Installation-Guide/#vagrant-development-environment)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks.git
$ cd FrameworkBenchmarks/deployment/vagrant-development/
$ vagrant up
<snip log messages>
$ vagrant ssh
$ cd FrameworkBenchmarks
$ toolset/run-tests.py --install server --test http-kit --mode verify
<snip log messages>
  Verification Summary

| Test: http-kit
|       fortune     : PASS
|       plaintext   : PASS
|       db          : PASS
|       update      : PASS
|       json        : PASS
|       query       : WARN
================================================================================
```